# Getting nested fields in a Flink API Table fromDatastream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I've got a nested datastream POJO that I turned into a table with the table API.
Inside the POJO lies a nested body with various fields such as "media_id".

When I use a sqlQuery, I can easily access said fields like this :

```
SELECT body.media_id FROM myTable
```

But I'd like to use the table API and define this field with a schema like this:

```
Table myTable = tEnv.fromDataStream(source, Schema.newBuilder()
                .column("body.media_id", "STRING")
                .build());
```

Unfortunately, doing so returns an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Cannot resolve field [body.media_id], input field list:[body, headers, id, ts, url].
```

Could you point out what I forgot/did wrong and a possible fix?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you declaring a column `"body.media_id"` of type **STRING** and for Flink `.` (point) it's just a character here.

```
.column("body.media_id", "STRING")
```

it's the same if it was `_` instead of `.` -> `"body_media_id"`

In your case column **body** is not a STRING but something like ROW of some fields. `ROW<media_id STRING, foo STRING>`